# Error: No handler for requested intent at WebhookClient.handleRequest

Tags: google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Default intent calling a cloud function gives error

```
Error: No handler for requested intent
at WebhookClient.handleRequest (/user_code/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:287:29)
at exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment.functions.https.onRequest (/user_code/index.js:73:11)
at cloudFunction (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:57:9)
at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:783:7
at /var/tmp/worker/worker.js:766:11
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:128:9)
```

as my webresponse in diagnostic info log shows this.

```
             {
              "responseId": "86043a10-8bc2-4ee7-8e8b-1e997289ad7c",
              "queryResult": {
                "queryText": "hi",
                "action": "input.welcome",
                "parameters": {},
                "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
                "fulfillmentText": "Hi. Am Uma. Kindly let me know your experience facing an issue.",
                "fulfillmentMessages": [
                  {
                    "text": {
                      "text": [
                        "Hi. Am Uma and welcome to support. Kindly let me know your experience facing an issue."
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "outputContexts": [
                  {
                    "name": "projects/handymanticketagent/agent/sessions/e416a522-da87-ebd1-348e-9fdea1efbf65/contexts/defaultwelcomeintent-followup",
                    "lifespanCount": 2
                  }
                ],
                "intent": {
                  "name": "projects/handymanticketagent/agent/intents/c58f706f-6cb6-499d-9ce2-459e8054ddc1",
                  "displayName": "Default Welcome Intent"
                },
                "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
                "diagnosticInfo": {
                  "webhook_latency_ms": 10001
                },
                "languageCode": "en"
              },
              "webhookStatus": {
                "code": 4,
                "message": "Webhook call failed. Error: Request timeout."
              }
            }
```

Based on the stack overflow answers here, Have added an intent mapped to function but am still getting error and could progress further. Where and how the cloud function console says am missing a handler for my request?

[image]

[image]

Update : As @prisoner said, including my cloud function code.

```
            'use strict';

            const functions = require('firebase-functions');
            const admin = require('firebase-admin');
            const { WebhookClient } = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

            process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:*'; // enables lib debugging statements
            admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
            const db = admin.firestore();

            exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
                console.log(request.body.queryResult.fulfillmentText);
                console.log(request);
                console.log(response);
                const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
                console.log(agent);
                function writeToDb(agent) {
                    // Get parameter from Dialogflow with the string to add to the database
                    const databaseEntry = agent.parameters.databaseEntry;
                    console.log(databaseEntry);
                    // Get the database collection 'dialogflow' and document 'agent' and store
                    // the document  {entry: "<value of database entry>"} in the 'agent' document
                    const dialogflowAgentRef = db.collection('dialogflow').doc('agent');
                    console.log(dialogflowAgentRef);
                    return db.runTransaction(t => {

                        t.set(dialogflowAgentRef, { entry: databaseEntry });
                        console.log(Promise.resolve('Write complete'));
                        return Promise.resolve('Write complete');
                    }).then(doc => {
                        agent.add('Wrote "${databaseEntry}" to the Firestore database.');
                        return null;
                        }).catch(err => {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log(err.stack);
                            }
                        console.log('Error writing to Firestore: ${err}');
                        agent.add('Failed to write "${databaseEntry}" to the Firestore database.');

                    });
                }

                function readFromDb(agent) {
                    console.log(agent);
                    // Get the database collection 'dialogflow' and document 'agent'
                    const dialogflowAgentDoc = db.collection('dialogflow').doc('agent');
                    console.log(dialogflowAgentDoc);
                    // Get the value of 'entry' in the document and send it to the user
                    return dialogflowAgentDoc.get()
                        .then(doc => {
                            if (!doc.exists) {
                                agent.add('No data found in the database!');
                            } else {
                                agent.add(doc.data().entry);
                            }
                            return Promise.resolve('Read complete');
                        }).catch(() => {
                            agent.add('Error reading entry from the Firestore database.');
                            agent.add('Please add a entry to the database first by saying, "Write <your phrase> to the database"');
                        });
                }
                function defaultwelcomeintent_function(agent) {
                    console.log(agent);
                } 
                // Map from Dialogflow intent names to functions to be run when the intent is matched
                let intentMap = new Map();
                intentMap.set('defaultwelcomeintent-followup', defaultwelcomeintent_function);
                intentMap.set('ReadFromFirestore', readFromDb);
                intentMap.set('WriteToFirestore', writeToDb);
                console.log(intentMap);
                agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
            });
```

Comment: Can you [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55615377/edit) to include the source code for your webhook fulfillment? The error suggests a problem with your code.

Comment: Thanks for giving a cue. Have updated question with fix. Thanks again.

Comment: What was the fix?

Answer (score 0):

The diagnostic info says that the intent's display name for that fulfillment is "Default Welcome Intent":

```
"intent": {
    "name": "projects/handymanticketagent/agent/intents/c58f706f-6cb6-499d-9ce2-459e8054ddc1",
    "displayName": "Default Welcome Intent"
},
```

So you'd need to create a mapping for it like this:
`intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', defaultwelcomeintent_function);`

Where `defaultwelcomeintent_function` is the handler you have defined within your cloud function.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the **exact error from Dialogflow** : `Error: No handler for requested intent`, in my case I'm using async/await in order to make synchronous calls through a cloud function in dialogflow fulfillement.

I noticed that in one of my main function mapped to an agent, I wasn't returning anything. Since the function was using **async** I added a return statment with the promise that I was waiting for at the beggining.

```
async function getInfo(agent) {
    var hh = await getUserInfos(request.body.originalDetectIntentRequest.payload.uuid);
    
// Do what you want here 
    var yy = hh.aa[0].zz.yy;
    agent.setFollowupEvent({ "name": "xxx", "parameters": { "xxx": yy } });

// Return your promise
    return hh;
}
```