# actions on google user.storage clears out with every post call from the user-at the same coversation. how do i save the data of the conversation?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am trying to save the data through the conversation with `user.storage`, I am accessing the `user.storage` like this:

```
app.post('/', express.json(), (req, res) => {

  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request: req, response: res })
  let personalD=new personalDetails(agent)

  function personal_details(){
    personalD.foo()
  }

  let intentMap = new Map()
  intentMap.set('inform.PersonalDetails',personal_details) 
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap)
}


//that's the personalDetails class:

class PersonalDetails{
    constructor(agent){
        this.agent=agent;
        this.conv=this.agent.conv();
    }

    foo() {    
        this.conv.user.storage.name=this.agent.parameters.name;
        this.conv.user.storage.age=this.agent.parameters.age;
        this.conv.user.storage.gender=this.agent.parameters.gender;

        const gotname = this.conv.user.storage.name==''?0:1
        const gotage = this.conv.user.storage.age==''?0:1
        const gotgender =this.conv.user.storage.gender==''?0:1

        const name=this.conv.user.storage.name;
        const gender=this.conv.user.storage.gender;

        if (gotname && !gotage&&!gotgender) 
          this.agent.add(`Ok, ${name}, How old are you? and what is you'r gender?`)
        else if (gotname && gotage&&!gotgender) 
          this.agent.add(`Ok, ${name}, What gender you belong to`)
        else if(gotname && !gotage&&gotgender) 
          this.agent.add(`Ok, ${name}, How old are you?`)
        else if (!gotname && gotage&&gotgender) 
          this.agent.add(`What's your name please?`)
        else if (!gotname && !gotage&&gotgender) 
          this.agent.add(`Well dear ${gender}, What is your name and how old are you`)
        else if(!gotname && gotage&&!gotgender) 
          this.agent.add('Let me know what is your name and what is your gender')
        else if (!gotname && !gotage&&!gotgender) 
          this.agent.add(`I want to get to know you before we begin. what is you'r name?`)
    }
}

module.exports=PersonalDetails;
```

Dialogflow wants from the user three entites: name, age and gender. When the user does not provide all of them the code does some logic to see what is missing.

The problem is that at first I enter lets say name and age, and then it asks the user about the gender, when the user enteres the gender it's already forgetting the name and the age... 
please help

Comment: Have you enabled the correct users settings on your Google account? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57252258/google-assitant-app-not-storing-user-information/57252839#57252839 If not, this can prevent the values from being stored.

Comment: thank's. yes i have it's enabled and also conv.user.verification is VERIFIED but still not working...

Answer (score 1):

In your dialogflow fulfillment code, you are initializing parameters in user.storage on **every** request from the intent, instead of only when you have a value from the user. This code is your problem:

```
this.conv.user.storage.name=this.agent.parameters.name;
this.conv.user.storage.age=this.agent.parameters.age;
this.conv.user.storage.gender=this.agent.parameters.gender;
```

You have to set the user.storage only once and then, you can use it anywhere directly.

```
app.intent('GetUserName', (conv, {name}) => {
  conv.user.storage.name= name; 
  conv.ask(`Hi, ${conv.user.storage.name}!.
  Please tell me how can I help you? `);
});

app.intent('AboutSC', (conv) => {
  conv.ask(`well ${conv.user.storage.name}.  What more would you like to know? `);
});
```

You can use the `user.storage` parameters directly. But using variable/constants that are initialized on every request will change the value everytime & will not help.

Comment: okay thank you for you'r response. that's right, but what if the dialogflow enters the 'GetUserName' intent more than once? and in the conv.user.storage i initilize more variables and each time just the ones i have recieved in the current call?   and also i did try it you'r way and not with  : intentMap.set('inform.PersonalDetails',personal_details)  and no matter how i recieve the intent call i get this error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: No handler for requested intent  at WebhookClient.handleRequest

Comment: After understanding the flow where you want to capture - name, gender, age of a user. Then it should be done using only one intent with three parameters. And ask the user to tell all the details, then only he/she can move forward in the conversation. And by this approach, you will enter the GetUserName only once with all the parameters. If you are using dialogflow, then in the conversation make these parameters mandatory (Required) to stop the user from not telling all the mandatory details.

Comment: For the error that you've mentioned, please check the name of your intent is matched to that written in function in code. And also refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55615377/error-no-handler-for-requested-intent-at-webhookclient-handlerequest it is updated with solution

Comment: about your second comment-thanks that fixed it! and the first one- in the begining i actually set the parameters as required but i wanna use the webhook client for slot filling. this intent is just an example but i have other intents in my project where the user can response things like 'yes' or 'no' and since i have few required entities in one intent i cannot do anything like follow up intent becuse first it wont leave the intent-to go to the follow up untill all required entities are full and second the agent wont know what entity the 'yes' or 'no' refers to. do you understand the problem?